# Macro excel: Paste values and update 2 cells

Tags: vba, excel

I apologize for being newbie as I am having difficulty with this concept. I really don't know where to start.

I just need a code in Sheet2 using an 'Update Button' to do the following:

In sheet1, this information will come from different Team Leaders as duplicate or even triplicate records shown in example 'Seat no. 1.2' can occur.

In sheet2, under 'Seat No.', this is constant and will never change (serves as my reference for my other Pivot and lookup codes)

In sheet2 columns, under 'User 1', the code will paste the 1st value detected; Under 'User2', the code will paste the 2nd value detected; Under unassign, the code will paste the 3rd value detected

In sheet2 column under Status, it will show Solo if only 1user, 'Sharing' if there are 2 users and 'Vacant' if no user.

Note: only two users are allowed for every Seat No.

[image: Simplified data for seat plan with sharing]

Hope you can help me. Thank you so much

Comment: Kindly share the current code you are using.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. "I don't know where to start" - Start with doing your research and writing some code. Then update your question when you get stuck at a specific point so we can help out with that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use macro for this. In **user 1** column use this:

=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$50,2,0)),"",VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$50,2,0)),

where 50 replace with number of your rows.

In **user 2** use this:

=IF(SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$50,Sheet2!A2)>1,IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2,OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$50,0),0,50-MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$50,0),2),2,0)),"",VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2,OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$50,0),0,7-MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$50,0),2),2,0)),"")

and again replace 50 with number of your rows.

In **status** column, use *IF* with *SUMIF*.

And in **Unassign** column, use vlookup like in first column,  but from down to up. There is lot of articles about it. Dont forget to use if in start, which will check if there is 3 IDs for seat.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't need VBA unless you insist to do so:

**User1** column:

`=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$9,2,0)=0,"",VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$9,2,0)),"")`

**User2** column (array formula, press **`Ctrl + Shift + Enter`** keys simultaneously):

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9,SMALL(IF($A2=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9,ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9)-ROW($A$2)+1),2)),"")`

**Status** column:

`=IF(COUNT(B2:C2)=0,"Vacant",IF(COUNT(B2:C2)=1,"Solo","Sharing"))`

**Unassign** column (array formula, press **`Ctrl + Shift + Enter`** keys simultaneously):

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9,SMALL(IF($A2=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9,ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9)-ROW($A$2)+1),3)),"")`

Hope this helps.